# glUnmapBuffer - return value and error code

Tags: opengl

Looking at glUnmapBuffer at the moment, according to some docs it returns GLboolean to indicate success (GL_TRUE) or failure (GL_FALSE).  Presumably if it fails it sets the GL error.

My question is under what circumstances you would need to check to see if it returned with GL_TRUE in release builds, assuming you're checking glGetError after every OpenGL call in debug builds?

Or rather, why would this function need to return a bool success/fail when other OpenGL functions do not? I'm looking for the organising principle here, i.e. can it sometimes return GL_FALSE without having set the gl error?

EDIT:

OK, I found the answer.  Not sure whether to leave this up because it's interesting.  [On this page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Mapping):

> "Because of its low-level nature, these protections have to be
>   relaxed. Therefore, it is possible that, during the time a buffer is
>   mapped, some kind of corruption happens. If this occurs, calling
>   glUnmapBuffer​ will return GL_FALSE. At that point, the contents of
>   the buffer in question are considered undefined. It may have your
>   data, or it may have random garbage."

So as I'm specifying Windows 7 or later, I don't need to consider it (I think).  Ironically, one of the reasons I switched out of Direct 3D into OpenGL was precisely this (with Direct 3D 9.0).

Comment: If you find an answer to your own question, *write an answer*. You can even accept it later!

Comment: Ironically, the reasons given for the need to check are total bullshit, as you're not writing to video memory on the one platform where such a thing could happen, but to locked pages in main memory. There is no reason why (or how) they should "go away" or be "corrupted". But still, it is _allowable_ to fail, and under Windows XP it _will_ indeed fail on a screenmode change (for no good reason, really, but apparently drivers just throw _everything_ away on a mode change, or something the like), so you have no option but to _always_ check -- whether the reasoning is valid or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [it's not a regular OpenGL error](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glMapBuffer.xml):

> (...) This can occur for system-specific reasons that affect the availability of graphics memory, such as screen mode changes. In such situations, GL_FALSE is returned and the data store contents are undefined. An application must detect this rare condition and reinitialize the data store.

This special mechanism was undoubtfully introduced to separate such cases from typical user interaction errors caught by `glGetError`.

Comment: I need more precise knowledge about "reinitialize data store" does that Mean I have to recreate a new BufferObject, re-do all bindings, or just have I to re-upload data by trying glBufferData and then glMapBuffer (also should I do that immediatly or the next frame)?

Comment: @DarioOO I suppose just supplying data again should do the trick, while full recreation is on the safe side. It's going to incur a perf penalty anyway, so I'd wait till next frame if and only if you could render without this particular buffer.

Comment: ok thanks:) next frame is ok, i'm using MapBuffer only for async stuff, and that stuff is double buffered so required next frame. perfect and thanks for suggestion :)